# Heroku production setting Cache-Control differently from local production

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, ruby-on-rails-3.2, rack, http-caching

I have an app running on heroku at http://chesseng.herokuapp.com/ when I visit the page with chrome and its caching disabled I get a response header for application-fingerprint.css that is something like

```
Cache-Control:private
Connection:keep-alive
Content-Encoding:gzip
Content-Type:text/css
Date:Wed, 17 Oct 2012 00:17:19 GMT
Last-Modified:Tue, 16 Oct 2012 03:13:38 GMT
Status:200 OK
transfer-encoding:chunked
Vary:Accept-Encoding
X-Rack-Cache:miss
```

However if I start up a local instance with `rails s -e production` and visit it the response header for application-fingerprint.css is something like

```
Age:5119
Cache-Control:public, max-age=31536000
Connection:Keep-Alive
Content-Encoding:gzip
Content-Length:95828
Content-Type:application/javascript
Date:Tue, 16 Oct 2012 23:01:27 GMT
Etag:"0bf9e9837d421c2e28be1ef4f0794a48"
Last-Modified:Tue, 16 Oct 2012 01:07:17 GMT
Server:WEBrick/1.3.1 (Ruby/1.9.3/2012-04-20)
Vary:Accept-Encoding
X-Content-Digest:add442e2036c1e6e9f4860dcc44496582a5c91b1
X-Rack-Cache:fresh
X-Request-Id:b89de17e397ac7b60acfe500e8d15df9
X-Runtime:0.001632
X-Ua-Compatible:IE=Edge,chrome=1
```

Why are the caching related fields like Cache-Control, Etag so different compared to heroku? Presumably I want heroku to return Cache-Control:public, max-age=31536000. But I need to first understand why `Cache-Control:public, max-age=31536000` is being set in my local production mode. Its puzzling because if I set `config.static_cache_control = "public, max-age=3600"` in `config/environments/production.rb` and start up a local server in production it still gives back `max-age=31536000` and seems to ignore `max-age=3600`

Comment: Is your Heroku `RAILS_ENV` set to `production`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the `X-Rack-Cache` headers it looks like you’re using the [rack-cache middleware](http://rtomayko.github.com/rack-cache/) which would affect the caching headers. Since locally your resource is in the cache (`X-Rack-Cache:fresh`), but on Heroku it isn’t (`X-Rack-Cache:miss`) that would explain the difference.

Try removing rack-cache from your middleware stack and see if the differences go away.

Comment: How did rack-cache become part of my rails app. There doesn't seem to be any explicit dependency on it yet it appears in my Gemfile.lock

Comment: @user782220 after a closer look, it seems Rails itself uses rack-cache. Try adding `config.action_dispatch.rack_cache = false` to disable it, and see if that clears up what’s happening.

Comment: That doesn't seem to be quite the cause. Adding `config.action_dispatch.rack_cache = false` gives back the following which still has `max-age` set.  `Cache-Control:public, max-age=31536000`

 `Connection:close
 Content-Encoding:gzip
   Content-Type:text/css
    Date:Wed, 17 Oct 2012 22:18:25 GMT
    ETag:"70c612ba1cb2b23dfc1b927194d53524"
    Last-Modified:Sat, 13 Oct 2012 02:52:50 GMT
    Status:200 OK
    Vary:Accept-Encoding
    X-Request-Id:d4205ea8d1fa0f4d2405f7c299dbfaee
    X-Runtime:0.485778
    X-UA-Compatible:IE=Edge,chrome=1'

Comment: @user782220 Do you have `config.assets.compile = true` set? Looking at http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html#live-compilation, sprockets sets `max-age=31536000` if you use live compilation.

Comment: I do have `config.assets.compile = true` set. Setting that to false got rid of the `max-age=31536000`. But now I'm seeing `max-age=3600` always. For that I started another [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12945170/config-static-cache-control-public-max-age-1000-being-ignored). On a side note why would sprockets sets to `max-age=31536000`. Doing something different from precompile seems to violate the principle of least surprise.